# WPF : Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed

Tags: wpf, gridview, telerik, messagebox, radgridview

I Have a WPF Project, When i try to Run This Code On RowLoad Event I got below Error :

```
private void ParentGridView_OnRowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if(((RadGridView)sender).Columns != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((RadGridView)sender).Columns.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Error : Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.

**Note That the GridView Control is Telerik RadGridView**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442943/dispatcher-throws-invalidoperationexception-on-messagebox-show-in-textchanged-ev) describes the same situation as yours.  (It references this [answer on a different website](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44962927-006e-4629-9aa3-100357861442)).

The dispatcher processing is suspended to avoid reentrancy problems when updating the visual tree.

If you really need to display a message box in response to your "Row Loaded" event, you need to defer the call using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke().

So, replace:

```
MessageBox.Show(((RadGridView)sender).Columns.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

with:

```
var msg = ((RadGridView)sender).Columns.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(msg)));
```

If this code is in a WPF object, then the `Dispatcher` property is available.  Otherwise, you need to get it from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you! I was faced with this exception when I using "DragDrop" a Textbox control from window to another window in WPF.