# Can I use Invoke instead of BeginInvoke to address suspension of Dispatcher processing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

One of our clients has reported an issue with one of our Add-ins becoming unresponsive. The error reported contains a stack trace that goes deep into the bowels of WPF and I won't distract you with that. Suffice to say that the top level error reads:

**Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.**

The same code works perfectly on my, and as far as I know any other, machine. All the code does is instantiate a WPF window and call its .ShowDialog() method.

Looking through issues with the same error, I find answers such as this:
[Dispatcher throws InvalidOperationException on Messagebox.Show in Textchanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442943)
or
[WPF : Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452864)

In both cases the answer provided is to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

The problem with that is that this call is **asynchronous** and I need to wait for user response. So I use Dispatcher.Invoke instead:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() oAIC.ShowDialog(), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal)
```

Once again this works perfectly on my machine but that means nothing. The original code worked perfectly on my machine, too.

**So my question is:**

**Is this even worth pursuing? Or is the fact that I use .Invoke instead of .BeginInvoke equivalent to me just using the original .ShowDialog() directly so I'm wasting my time?**

Suffice to say that the client in question is not of the cooperative kind. Other clients would be happy for me to give them a trial version and report back, but this person simply wants a solution and doesn't want to be bothered with anything else. As this has never been reported by any other client I can't even find another "guinea pig" to try this on, so all I have left is the option to ask it here in the hope that someone with sufficient expertise can tell me "yes this is a good way forward" or "you're wasting your time". Sorry if this doesn't quite fit the model for asking questions here but I'm at the end of my rope...

**further clarification after seeing Peregrine's answer**

The code is part of an Office Add-in (in this case for Microsoft Word). The WPF dialog I'm trying to display pops up several levels down from a button click in the Ribbon Bar.

I put the code behind the button click into a function

```
DoTheButtonCode()
```

and called it as follows

```
Await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(AddressOf DoTheButtonCode)
```

When I tried this, an error was raised:

*An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.*

Now this is the weird thing. In the original Button Click event, the apartmentstate of system.threading.thread.currentthread is STA **but** when I then step into the DoTheButtonCode and I check system.threading.thread.currentthread its apartmentstate is MTA

**further clarification**

Ok - tried something else:

Changed DoTheButtonCode to an Async Function:

```
Private Async Function DoTheButtonCode() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Integer)
```

The button Click event handler method is now defined Private Async Sub, and within it I call

```
Await DoTheButtonCode()
```

This actually works, apart from this niggling warning that appears in the function definition of DoTheButtonCode: "this async method lacks 'Await' operators and so will run synchronously" (etc)

So while this does work I suspect that I'm kidding myself here.

I think I'm about ready to give up. I'll just add a try/catch construct around my original ShowDialog call and if the error is raised at least it will simply do nothing rather than crash :(

Thanks for all your help, Peregrine

Comment: `Task.Run` will use the default scheduler which will schedule onto a thread pool thread, which will not be STA.  You can write a custom scheduler which will schedule onto STA threads; I leave it as an exercise for the reader, it should be easy to find examples using the googles.  For UI-related things, the bigger issue would be that it would put it on a non-UI thread, so you would need to dispatch back to the UI thread in `DoTheButtonCode` if you want to do UI-related things there.

Comment: If you want to wait for a user response, you should be able to `Await` a `BeginInvoke` call; in fact, in my experience, you get a compiler error if you *don't* await it (I have warning disable pragmas in my code for the instances where I want to fire and forget a BeginInvoke).

Comment: Thanks Craig. I'll keep that in mind in case I have to revisit my "blunt instrument" approach as stated at the end of the OP. For now I will just Catch the error, ignore it and do nothing, in the hope that this is a "one off" issue for this particular user and if they click the button a second time it'll be fine as it is for literally everybody else. If that fails, yes, I'll look into creating a custom scheduler but I hope I don't have to :)

Comment: I misremembered, you don't even necessarily need to write it, there's a Microsoft parallel extensions extras pack that includes an STA task scheduler.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the extra clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something very similar in my library for displaying message dialogs in a MVVM pure manner.

The only differences I can see between my code and yours is

1. I'm using `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()` rather than `Dispatcher.Invoke()` - which makes the call awaitable.
2. I'm creating my dialog window inside the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() call - it's not clear where your `oAIC` window is being created.

```
private async Task<perDialogButton> _ShowDialogAsync(object viewModel, object content, string title, perDialogButton buttons, perDialogIcon dialogIcon)
{
    // get control associated with ViewModel instance
    var associatedControl = ... 

    return await associatedControl.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        var window = new perDialog
        {
            // set dialog properties 
            ... 
        };

        window.ShowDialog();

        return window.SelectedButton;
    });
}
```

Mode details, and the full source code on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-message-dialogs/)

Comment: Note that you can also [await BeginInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413367/1136211). The important difference between BeginInvoke and InvokeAsync is the argument type.

Comment: Thank you very much Peregrine, but I think I'm fighting a losing battle here.... I'll post an explanation below by using the Answer Your Question button as I can't include enough detail in a comment..... Bear with me :)

Comment: ok it seems like that is not the correct thing to do so I will add further clarification by editing the question.

Comment: @Peregrine - I've added the further clarification in my original post. Thanks for your help but I think I've hit the proverbial brick wall. Hopefully this will be of some limited use to someone else.